# What are the finite subgraphs of the 2-dimensional square lattice?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

Consider the infinite graph $G = (V,E)$, where $V = \mathbb{Z}^2$ and each element is adjacent to its 4 cardinal neighbours, i.e.
  $$ E = \{(u,v) \in V^2 : \text{dist}(u,v) = 1\} $$
What are the finite subgraphs of $G$? There are several properties a graph $H$ must satisfy to be (isomorphic to) a subgraph of $G$:

- $H$ must be planar
- Every vertex in $H$ must have degree at most 4
- $H$ must be bipartite

The above conditions aren't sufficient. I initially hoped the key was in the cycles of $H$, but there is even an example of a tree satisfying the above conditions which is not a subgraph of $G$, for instance, this tree: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDVST.jpg

So my question is: is there a nice characterization of the finite subgraphs of $G$? Or at least an efficient algorithm for determining whether a particular finite graph is a subgraph of $G$?

Comment: What about adding (assuming $H$ is connected) *$H$ is bipartite* ? Never mind, this is not enough. We may consider a root node, four edges departing from it, three extra edges departing from each child node. This is connected and bipartite but it clearly cannot be embedded in the square lattice, as already remarked.

Comment: On the other hand, by denoting as $N(u)$ the neighbourhood of a vertex $u$ and as $N(E)$ the neighbourhood of some $E\subset V$, the constraints $|N(u)|\leq 4, |N(N(u))|\leq 9, |N(N(N(u)))|\leq 16, \ldots$ have to be fulfilled.

Comment: That's a good point; while being bipartite still isn't enough it's a nice strengthening of the "no odd cycle" condition; I'll put that in the question.

Your second condition is interesting; I had a similar tree counterexample, and in my head I had this notion that the graph can't "expand too crazily", which this seems to encapsulate. I'll have to see if I can show that adding that condition is/isn't enough.

Comment: This tree satisfies that property as well, but isn't a subgraph of $G$: https://imgur.com/a/LoxQ5

I'm still interested in the idea of "limiting the growth" of $H$; I'll see if I kind find similar ways to add to the conditions

Comment: It just occurred to me that bipartite isn't a strengthening of "no odd cycles"; the two conditions are equivalent. I'm leaving it as bipartite, though, it feels like a nicer condition